# VueJS - Define components in secondary .js file

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue.js

I have this situation: I have an Laravel app that is not an SPA. But I use Vue in many components of my application, using single-file components and all of that.

But I have some components that I only want to load in some pages, for performance reasons. But, when I register a component in a second .js file, I always get an error like this:

> Property or method "addresses" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
>   (found in )

My structure is something like this:

**app.js**

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
import ModalMessage from './../components/ModalMessage.vue';
import FlashMessage from './../components/FlashMessage.vue';

window.MainVue = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        loading: false
    },

    components: { ModalMessage, FlashMessage }
});
```

All of this work's perfectly fine. But when I introduce a new `.js` file, I always get the error mentioned above.

Example:

**account.js**

```
window.UserAddresses = new Vue({
    el: '#user-addresses',

    data: {
        addresses: []
    },

    methods: {

    }
});
```

The HTML for the `#user-addresses` is:

```
<div id="user-addresses">
    <table class="table">
        <tr v-for="address in addresses">
            <td>testing</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And I always get the error:

> Property or method "addresses" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
>   (found in )

In this internal page that generates the error, my JS files are included like this:

```
<script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/account.js"></script>
```

The account.js Vue instance is mounted before generates the error.

My question is: Is there a way to work with Vue in multiple `.js` files? I also didn't want to declare all my subcomponents data in my root Vue instance.

Is there a way to make this work?

**UPDATE**

I'm using webpack for compiling all files.

Comment: are you including the scripts for all of your vue instances in the html file

Comment: Just added in the question how the files are included.

Comment: There should be no problem including additional Vues in other script files, so something else is going on here. Is it possible `#user-addresses` is inside the template of MainVue?

Comment: Does `div#user-addresses` appear inside `#app` in your html?

Comment: Yes, div#user-addresses is a children of #app. There's no way to make it work?

Comment: @LuisDalmolin No. It would, in that case, need to be a component. But you can define it as a component in another file just as easily.

Comment: Declaring as a component, I got this error: "Unknown custom element: <user-addresses>". I declared like this:`Vue.component('user-addresses', require('./../../components/UserAddresses'));`

Comment: @LuisDalmolin Actually, you are compiling app.js using webpack or something similar?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention. I'm using webpack.

Comment: @LuisDalmolin Are you including the single compiled app.js on every page? If you have different pages, you may want to have multiple entry points in your webpack config so that a custom file is built for each page.

Comment: @BertEvans Yes, the app.js file is on every single page. Then in the internal pages I add only the custom javascript for that page. I wanted to avoid have one single file for each page, but if there's no other way, I'm going this way. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In general your top example looks just right and nothing I would see out of order. The problem though you describe with the addresses probably comes from how you use the `UserAddresses`.
I would guess you have it nested inside the `#app` element on the page.
The problem here is, you can't nest two Vue root instances in each other.

```
new Vue({...}) // get a Vue rootinstance
```

What you probably want to do is use a Component. You can use global components for this, and therefor it's fine to have one global root instance.

```
window.UserAddresses = Vue.component('user-addresses', {
   data () {
     return {
      addresses: []
     }
   }
   ... // rest of your component code
}
```

You can get more information here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: Using like this `Vue.component('user-addresses', require('./../../components/UserAddresses'));`, in a separated JS file, I got this error: "Unknown custom element: <user-addresses>". PS: I'm using webpack.

Comment: and UserAddresses in this case is a simple object? Be sure it has a `template` and be save and add a `name` attribute as well.

Comment: In this case UserAddresses is a `.vue` file, and I'm also using vue loader with webpack.